# Does Salesforce support PKCE validation in Web server flow?

Tags: security, oauth2

In Salesforce OAuth2.0 Web Server flow, there is an option to not require a client key. But I am not sure whether it supports OAuth 2.0 RFC 7636: https://oauth.net/2/pkce/, which is the PKCE validation. In the document it says:

> It requires additional support by the authorization server, so it is
>   only supported on certain providers.

I tried to search through Salesforce documents but didn't find anything related. And I don't see related code base regarding this validation as well. The most similar I have seen so far is this question on Salesforce forum: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005ag9QAA. But it is also unanswered.

Any thoughts about this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PKCE is an optional part of Web Server flow. From the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5):

> `code_challenge`—Specifies the SHA256 hash value of the `code_verifier`
>   value in the token request to help prevent authorization code
>   interception attacks. [...]
>
> If the `code_challenge` value is provided in the authorization request
>   and a `code_verifier` value is provided in the token request, Salesforce
>   compares the `code_challenge` to the `code_verifier`.
>
> - If the
>     `code_challenge` is invalid or doesn’t match, the login fails with the
>     `invalid_request` error code.
> - If the `code_challenge` value is provided in
>     the authorization request, but a `code_verifier` value isn’t provided in
>     the token request, the login fails with the `invalid_grant` error code.

Comment: Can this flow be done purely from the client of a web application? I ran into CORS issues trying to implement Web Server Flow (with or without PKCE) via a javascript POST request. Since Authorization Code with PKCE is now preferred over Implicit Grant, can this be done with Salesforce?

Comment: @TracyMoody SF doesn't allow cross-origin requests on unauthenticated resources, including oAuth endpoints. It is possible to implement authorization code grant (aka Web Server flow) in SPA or similar client-heavy app but you'll have to be careful about these requests, e.g. issue a 302 redirect from JS to grab the authorization code rather than a cross-origin fully-submerged-no-user-interaction request in JS.

Comment: Update: cross-origin requests on oAuth endpoints are [allowed](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_oauth_cors.htm&type=5&release=228) since Winter '21 release (Nov 2020)